# How can I retrieve a pinned file using the IPFS curl commands

Tags: curl, ipfs

Why can I not retrieve a file that I just pinned?

Here's a series of cURL commands that represent the problem:

#### First add a file

curl "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add?pin=false"  -X POST  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -F file=@"src/main/resources/ipfs.txt"

- Returns:
  {"Name":"ipfs.txt","Hash":"QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91","Size":"39"}

#### Make sure I can see it

curl -X POST "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/cat?arg=QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91"

- Returns:
  This is content stored in ipfs!

#### Then try to pin the same file

curl -X POST "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/pin/add?arg=/ipfs/QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91"

- Returns:
  {"Pins":["QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91"]}

#### Try to retrieve the pinned file:

curl -X POST "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/pin/ls?arg=/ipfs/QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91&type=all" -u "XXXX:YYYY"

- Returns:
  {"Message":"path '/ipfs/QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91' is not pinned","Code":0,"Type":"error"}

Why can I not find the file I just pinned?

Thanks

Comment: Is it as simple as you didn't specify your user credentials when pinning the file? When I try this on my local node, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you pin your CID, you must specify your user credentials so you're ensuring that you're pinning to your personal Infura node:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/pin/add?arg=/ipfs/QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91" -u "XXXX:YYYY"
```

Then when you list your pins:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/pin/ls?arg=/ipfs/QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91&type=all" -u "XXXX:YYYY"
```

It'll return the following:

```json
{"Keys":{"QmZn3etFvjekVf8ArX9vY21RQsP44YthbdWyfdrdSezp91":{"Type":"recursive"}}}
```